# Values to convert from Row into Column values without Pivot and loop/cursor IN SQL Server using Row number or Rank

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, rank, data-interchange

I want to convert the below data as shown in the output

```
DPPY_PFX    DPDP_ID DPRL_DP_ID  ROW_NUMBER   
-------------------------------------------
1315        D8703   D8692       1   
0219        D6010   D6012       1  
0219        D6010   D6013       2  
0219        D6010   D7993       3  
0219        D6010   D7994       4
```

Output

```
1315    D8703   D8692  
0219    D6010   D6012,D6013,D7993,D7994
```

I coded as below, but the value is not taken instead the count is alone taken.

```
DPPY_PFX    DPDP_ID 1   2   3   4  
0219    D6010   1   1   1   1  
1315    D8703   1   0   0   0
```

Query

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         DPPY_PFX,
         DPDP_ID,
         DPRL_DP_ID,
         ROW_NUMBER   
     FROM 
         ##pivot) AS StudentTable
PIVOT
    (COUNT (DPRL_DP_ID)
         FOR ROW_NUMBER IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])
    ) AS SchoolPivot
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want string aggregation:

```
select dppy_pfx, dpdp_id,
    string_agg(dprl_dp_id, ',') within group(order by row_number) dprl_dp_ids
from ##pivot
group by dppy_pfx, dpdp_id
```